# .net & admin rights - how to embed manifest file for 2 different scenarios

Tags: .net, uac, manifest, rights

I have one .net application which would be installed under "program files" running in 2 different modes:

- "ADVANCED_MODE" with all plugins
  enabled which should pop-up the UAC
  to run as administrator
- "BASIC_MODE" with only few plugins
  loaded which should work as normal
  user

What to do to solve this case?

If I embed a manifest file (`requireAdmin` set on), it will not work for BASIC_MODE. If I don't use any manifests, then I don't have the chance to popup the UAC in ADVANCED_MODE. If I use "`asInvoker`" or "`highestAvailable`" I get strange effects when I run the app from Program Files as normal user account: it closes immediately after startup without any crash.

What would you do? What are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use asInvoker in your manifest and when your app is started in ADVANCED_MODE (and you are not already admin), start a new instance of your app with ShellExecute and the "runas" verb.

These "strange effects" indicate that your app can't really run as non-admin (Without a manifest your app will run with some compatibility shims like file & registry redirection) You can use the [Microsoft Application Compatibility Toolkit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=24da89e9-b581-47b0-b45e-492dd6da2971&displaylang=en), [LUA Buglight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aaron_margosis/archive/2011/03/23/lua-buglight-2-1-1-with-support-for-win7-2008r2-sp1.aspx) and [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to look for standard user bugs...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, at least there is an explanation for these 'strange effects'. Although I cannot do what you suggested since my app accepts only one instance running on the system.

Comment: @Cristi: You can do the elevation stuff before checking for the mutex or whatever your instance check is doing...