# Is it possible to run Console Application under LocalSystem Account?

Tags: c#, console-application, impersonation, localsystem

Is it possible to run Console Application under LocalSystem Account programmatically in C#?

If yes, how can i do it ?

If not, why not ?

thanks

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952673/net-admin-rights-how-to-embed-manifest-file-for-2-different-scenarios

Comment: possible duplicate of [Impersonation in .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/impersonation-in-net)

Comment: these does not answer my questions! i asked if it is possible to start a console application under LocalSystem Account? And not if its possible to start it under a another user account...

Comment: I need code like on this page for impersonation as LocalService: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa378184(v=vs.85).aspx .But i need impersonation into LocalSystem Account...

Comment: i found a very good explanation: http://joco.name/2010/12/31/how-to-impersonate-the-windows-system-account-in-an-application/